# How is the OWIN OAuth 2 token actually created?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-web-api, oauth, owin

We have OWIN OAuth 2.0 working (thanks to [this fantastic post](http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/)) but needed some more insight into the actual process of converting the `ClaimsIdentity` into the actual `access_token` string in the HTTP response.

We're creating the `ClaimsIdentity` at this method in our OAuth Authorization Provider:

```
public class SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
{
    // <snip>
    public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        // validation, user checking code here

        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("sub", context.UserName));
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("role", "user")); 
        context.Validated(identity);
    }
}
```

And when we make the HTTP POST request as `grant_type=password&username=user007&password=jamesbond` (relax, password here is ok), we get the HTTP POST response body

`{"access_token":"9K8VtOBseU0-XZfdGe2_urn2HESY3jLkpgvowOQFPXsHeWNOrTlTVzfPu35ZEvr4AqSj_b0laesBegtVWuR8R-aItnNXw4vXiuCg0cTNMUKP_yfi89VhD446o2X6ffL8upwZVILpomweSweIVlDmwUDzIwf1ZqubrQ8vuiQDFu-_7vpjPwJ5yVvomQ75agsJWMZk-H_bVWSObds82aM8LCRJwb2bUJchr6_L1GP8xdXqRQz24uDhHvco-XByyMSMzZm-Qo0VVBbocbgP64OJulbihVG_W9e8G69UfbX99pIYiLyE4jixiUtjOKSiMYBISW3_fg","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":1799,"as:client_id":"","userName":"user007",".issued":"Fri, 31 Oct 2014 16:02:05 GMT",".expires":"Fri, 31 Oct 2014 16:32:05 GMT"}`

Question: What is the logic that creates the actual `access_token` string?

Some specific concerns within the question

1. What is the internal structure of that `access_token` string?
2. Is it encrypted or signed or both? What's the key that's used (assume IIS/Azure Cloud Service)?
3. How can we override the implementation that generates the actual string sent out and then checks the same token/string on subsequent accesses?

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Glad that my post was useful, please find answers as the below:

1 - This 'magical' string is an encrypted ***or*** signed string ([poor MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.machinekey.protect%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), speaks of encrypt or sign without clarity) that contains the deserialized version of all the claims and ticket properties for the signed in user. If in IIS mode, the encryption/signing is done via the "decryptionKey" and "validationKey" key values in **machineKey** node ([documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/w8h3skw9%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)). If running as a standalone OWIN application, the encryption uses the legacy DPAPI to protect it and that actually uses the obsolete 3DES algorithm ([documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995355.aspx)). The default implementation for it is in the [source code here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Owin.Security/DataHandler/SecureDataFormat.cs).

2 - Answered in point 1.

3 - Check my [new post](http://bitoftech.net/2014/10/27/json-web-token-asp-net-web-api-2-jwt-owin-authorization-server/) where I show how to issue signed Json web tokens instead of default access token.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: For the 3rd point of custom token, if one implements a custom `CustomTokenFormat : ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket>` and supplies it to the `AccessTokenFormat` property of `OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions`, how does one enforce it's validation at access time? Does that automatically happen by supplying the same `OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions` object (and therefore same `AccessTokenFormat`) to both `UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(..)` and `UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(..)` ?

Comment: You are correct, this happens automatically. The expiry time for the access token is set with the using the property `AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan` in `OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions` then this will be part of the `AuthenticationTicket` data properties where you can read the `ExpiresUtc` property in the custom class for `AccessTokenFormat`, you can check it here: [link](https://github.com/tjoudeh/JWTAspNetWebApi/blob/master/AuthorizationServer.Api/Formats/CustomJwtFormat.cs#l44-47)

Comment: @Taiseer How does the decryptionkey/validation key work with a load balancer in front of multiple server instances?

Comment: @VictorMukherjee - Did you ever find the answer to this question. That is exactly what I'm trying to understand... we're using multiple server instances hosted on windows azure, if the load balancer sends requests to different machines, will the access token only be valid on the server it was created on?